net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (By docker)
this error occured.
Environment : docker-compose, vue, spring, mysql, redis
docker works on oracle cloud server. because i deployed.
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234 <---example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: data
    volumes:
      - ./db/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    networks:
      - app-network
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 10

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6380:6380'
    networks:
      - app-network

  vue:
    container_name: front
    image: frontimage
    environment:
      VITE_API_URL: http://spring:8088/
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network

  spring:
    container_name: spring
    image: backimage
    ports:
      - '8088:8088'
    environment:
      DB_PASSWORD: 1234
      DB_USER: root
      DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://app-mysql:3306/data?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      JWT_SECRET: 1d5b94681dec98b3623a7827a489076cd2e28065d110034c27c17b360a39ae5d
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    depends_on:
      - app-mysql
      - redis
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


default.conf

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name viewgorithm.site;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /user {
        proxy_pass http://spring:8088;
    }
    location /algorithm {
        proxy_pass http://spring:8088;
    }
    location /user/post {
        proxy_pass http://spring:8088;
    }
    location /logout {
        proxy_pass http://spring:8088;
    }
}

.env
VITE_BASE_URL:http://spring:8088/

i changed docker network.
bridge -> host
but it's not working.
And spring project is no problem.
i think cors is fine.
.cors(c -> {
                            CorsConfigurationSource source = request -> {
                                var cors = new CorsConfiguration();
                   
                                cors.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
       
                                cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
      
                                cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                                cors.setAllowCredentials(false);
                                cors.setMaxAge(3600L);
                                return cors;
                            };
                            c.configurationSource(source);
                        }
                )

Previously, I accessed it with an ip address and there was no problem. However, after applying the domain, it says that it is not possible to communicate with the spring container.

Your browser-based application can't access the Docker hostnames or IP addresses; also see "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend.  Since everything is running behind a reverse proxy already, can you set VITE_API_URL: / with just a path?

THANKS for your help, My Problem has been solved.

Welcome to StackOverflow. If your question has been solved, it's a good idea to add & accept an answer to introduce the solution. This will help more people.
